# Dynamic NSStackView that resizes to fit its content

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode8, macos-sierra

I want to use an NSStackView as "floating" container for buttons. i.e. a horizontal NSStackView that acts as toolbar of sorts and contains a row of square buttons (with fixed size). In runtime, some buttons will be dynamically shown/hidden and I want this NSStackView to dynamically adjust its width according to the visible buttons (plus spacing, edges, etc).

So, this NSStackView would have:

- Fixed height
- Dynamic width based on its content
- Its exact position in parent view is not known in design time
- A row of NSButtons with fix sizes

I have a nib file that contains the NSStackView and its buttons, which I load in runtime:

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ToolbarView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)
toolbarView.detachesHiddenViews = true
toolbarView.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 100, y: 100))
```

I am struggling to find the exact combination of properties and constraints to make this behavior work. When I hide some buttons, the NSStackView detaches them but doesn't shrink to fit the shown buttons total width. I tried all NSStackView `NSStackViewDistribution` options.

I suspect I'm missing some constrains to make this work but all the NSStackView examples I find anchor the NSStackView to it's superview and I can't do that because its position in parent view is set in runtime.

Is there any way to make this work or do I need to fall back to manually calculating width from the visible buttons (which kind of makes using NSStackView pointless)?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the already-mentioned `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` and leading and top constraints, have you tried modifying the stack view's hugging priority?  Use a value of 1000 (required) to absolutely prevent the stack view from extending beyond its contents:

```
stackView.setHuggingPriority(1000, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. But the problem was that the constraints created from the auto resizing mask were preventing the NSStackView from resizing itself, so the priority didn't help. I think I understand now, more or less, what was my problem(s). (see my comment to @Taylor's answer).

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. It's a lot simpler if you forget about the autoresizing mask and just do everything with constraints.  That way you only have one layout system to think about. Just disable `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` as soon as you can (ideally before inserting into the view hierarchy) and don't touch it after that.  Just think of whatever you wanted the autoresizing mask to do and make constraints to do it.

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` on the stack view after loading it from the nib? If true, what is the `autoresizingMask`? (the default it should be .none).

If that is the case, then there are autoresizing mask constraints that hold the stack view's frame origin and size in place (i.e whatever gets loaded from the nib).

The best way to deal with this is to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false and then use constraints to position it in its parent view at runtime.

Comment: If I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false I need to add constraints manually to prevent the parent view from complaining about missing constraints. Do you know what constraints should I add in this case to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: It depends on exactly what you're trying to achieve with the dynamic positioning. But `stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 100).active = true; stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor, constant: 100).active = true` should be the moral equivalent to the frame origin set above. If that position can change later, you can keep a reference to the constraints and change their `constant` property.

Comment: I found that modifying the auto resizing mask before adding the NSStackView to its parent gives me the desired behavior with the right mask. But it seems that this only works on a plain parent NSView. When I tried to do the same on an nested view inside NSSplitView, it doesn't work. Looks like NSSplitView doesn't respect the auto resizing mask set on inner views and changes it internally. I didn't find any way to make it work with the auto resizing mask when the NSStackView is nested inside NSSplitView.